# What's the difference between model and props in `mobx-state-tree`?

Tags: mobx, mobx-state-tree

It seems to me that people are using `model` and `props` interchangeably. I try to find documents about props but failed. Could someone tell me the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `model` method creates a new model. It takes two parameters:

- name
- properties (optional)

You can create a new model and specify the properties. Or you can create the model first and then 'extend' it with the `props` method (props is short for properties). TodoOne and TodoTwo are the same.

```js
const TodoOne = types.model("Todo", {title: types.string, done: types.boolean})

const TodoTwo = types.model("Todo")
  .props({
    title: types.string, 
    done: types.boolean
  })
```

But how is this useful? Well the `props` method doesn't mutate the current type it creates a new one and extends it. This means that we can add or override existing props.

```js
const Todo = types.model("Todo", {title: types.string, done: types.boolean})

const ColorfulTodo = Todo.props({color: types.string}) // returns a new model with a new property

const DefaultTodo = Todo.props({done: false}) // returns a new model with done property overwritten to default to false
```

The `views` and `actions` methods can extend models in same way as the `props` method.

Answer (score 0):

Model needs properties.

```js
const Todo = types
    .model("Todo", {
        title: types.string,
        done: false
    })
```

In the example above we created a `Todo` model (MST model) with two properties:

`title` which is a `String`

`done` witch is a `Boolean` and defaults to `false`

So when you hear `props` they are referring to the properties of the model.